# How do I create separate boxes for photoset and caption on permalink page (css/html)?

Tags: html, css, permalinks, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I'm currently using tumblr as a host for my business website. Currently on the index page I have a single photo from the photoset which is linked to the permalink. At the moment the permalink just displays one post box with the photoset and the text at the bottom. I was hoping there might be a way to separate the {photoset} and {caption} of the permalink page into two boxes next to one another like a product page.

I've only seen this done once before in this theme, but the code is so confusingly written I can't make sense of it. https://zen-themes.com/install/level/?utm_source=internal&utm_medium=theme_single_menu&utm_campaign=install_level/

Any help is hugely appreciated!